Metropolis-Hastings algorithm doesn't converge to the global minimum
I calculated the total root mean squared error of 24 parameters that are estimated with metropolis hastings, I ran the algorithm for 100.000 iterations, and as the chain forward it reached a global minimum, but as it continued, more samples arrived, so the RMSE started to increase.

So my question is there a way to stop early? so I can stop at 25000 iterations?
I'm using the particle marginal metropolis hastings to construct the Markov chain and using particle filter to calculate the likelihood.

While we review existing criteria in our book, there is not absolute stopping rule that applies to every setting. Most fall victim of the "what you get Renewal brings a theoretical guarantee but it is hard to implement in practice. I do not understand the meaning of the RMSE in this example, unless you mean distance to the exact values of the parameters, which cannot be used in realistic settings.

@Xi'an Yes you are right, distance to the exact values of the parameters, yeah i know cannot be used in realist settings, it just for me too see how RMSE is changing over time

The minimum RMSE does not have to correspond to the sample reaching stationarity. If it goes up after 20k iterations, it may be due to a better exploration of the tails of the target distribution.

There has been lots of research into diagnostics for the convergence of an MCMC chain. See this review paper (Roy 2020) or this STAN manual, for example. One popular approach that you could consider, is the "Gelman-Rubin statistic" $(\hat R)$; see Gelman & Rubin 1992 or Gelman & Shirley 2011, for example. For a single variable, this generally works by running $J > 1$ chains in parallel and computing the "between chain" variance
$$B = \frac{L}{J-1}\sum_{j=1}^J\left(\bar x_j - \bar x_\star\right)^2,$$
and the average "within chain" variance
$$W = \frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^J\left(\frac{1}{L-1}\left(x_{j,i}-\bar x_j\right)^2\right).$$
Then we compute the statistic
$$\hat R = \frac{\frac{L-1}{L}W + \frac{1}{L}B}{W}$$
and we stop the chain when $\hat R$ is sufficiently close to $1$ (indicating convergence). If you only have the resources to run one chain, there is also a "split" version of the statistic. For a more recent reference and for possible extensions, consider the highly-cited paper Revisiting the Gelman-Rubin Diagnostic (Vats & Knudson 2021) (disclaimer: I haven't yet read this paper).

As to your problem with the increasing RMSE, I'm not sure exactly what's going on. Without more information, all I can do is make some blind guesses. It's possible that the chain is overfitting at first (leading to an artificially small RMSE) and so you need to run the chains longer for better convergence to the true posterior. Or else, maybe it's indicative of a bug in your code. Impossible to say without more information, but perhaps rigorously monitoring the convergence will provide you with useful information.
References
Roy, V. (2020). Convergence diagnostics for markov chain monte carlo. Annual Review of Statistics and Its Application, 7, 387-412.
Gelman, A., & Rubin, D. B. (1992). Inference from iterative simulation using multiple sequences. Statistical science, 7(4), 457-472.
Gelman, A., & Shirley, K. (2011). Inference from simulations and monitoring convergence. Handbook of markov chain monte carlo, 6, 163-174.
Vats, D., & Knudson, C. (2021). Revisiting the gelman–rubin diagnostic. Statistical Science, 36(4), 518-529
